# A large truck with 8 wheels and a car which are running across red lights are chased by the police. - Can a relative clause modify two nouns?

Tags: relative-clauses

**Example 1**

> A large truck with 8 wheels and a car **which are running across red lights** are chased by the police.

Can a relative clause modify two nouns like this?

Comment: The usual phrase is "running red lights", not "running *across* red lights".

Comment: "A large truck with 8 wheels" is usually "A large 8 wheeler truck".

Comment: Related: [Relative clause applies to all nouns in the list or the last noun only](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/307349/relative-clause-applies-to-all-nouns-in-the-list-or-the-last-noun-only). Please explore the 'related' panel here on the right too.